# Python and C++ repository structure

Tags: c++, architecture, python, repository

I'm refactoring the directory structure of a large Python repo that has a few dozen C and C++ files littered throughout. Is there a **suggested architecture for a Python package that contains C/C++ code within it?** What I have at the moment for my repo `foo` is:

```
foo/
├── LICENSE
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── docs/
├── examples/
├── foo/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── core/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── foo_tricks_slow.py
│   │   ├── foo_tricks_fast.cpp
│   │   └── foo_tricks_fast.mk
│   ├── experiments/
│   └── utils/
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests/  # Run with py.test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_foo.py
```

Each subdir `core/`, `experiments/`, `utils/`, and so on contains mostly python files, and some C/C++ files.

Some things I've heard mixed opinions on that I'd like to reach a conclusion on include

1. Putting tests outside the Python package
2. Putting source in a `src/` dir
3. Keeping a directory for Python and a directory for C/C++

Some sources of info I've looked at include:

A. [Filesystem structure of a Python project](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) by Jean-Paul Calderone

B. [cookiecutter](https://www.pydanny.com/cookie-project-templates-made-easy.html)

C. [Jeff Knupp's blog post](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/)

D. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261550/directory-structure-for-a-project-that-mixes-c-and-python) is close, but I don't have a self-contained C++ project, but rather some misc. files, each with their own `mk` file that gets accumulated when running the main Makefile.

E. Example repositories like Tensorflow, Keras, Nupic, Django

**Related**: I would like the repo to be installed and built with `pip install foo`. I'm unsure how this would also build the C/C++ files though. For example, `pip install tensorflow` accomplishes this. Perhaps that's for a followup SO question though.

Comment: Your folder structure does not constitute a software architecture.

Comment: [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) installs precompiled libraries. If you install it from sources, you need more steps than just `pip install tensorflow`

Comment: Would you explain more @RobertHarvey? Or if you're just arguing semantics, would you prefer "repo structure"?

Comment: "Folder structure" or "directory structure."